# Do I need dynamic meta tags in an isomorphic JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, isomorphic-javascript

I have an isomorphic web application. Right now I am not updating meta tags client side. I see there are tons of libraries that handle this. However, is it even necessary? When Google crawls a website does it do a "page refresh" when following links or does it navigate "client side"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this article about Google particularly, since that was the engine you asked about, [Will Google Find Your React Content?](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-seo/). Also, Yahoo, Bing, etc do not support JS in their crawlers.

Ideally, you will want to set those meta values in your template engines ([Jade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade), [EJS](http://ejs.co/), [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)) when the `index.html` file is rendered to the browser.